# How do I efficiently join all the possibilities in an array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

```
["Hey", ["What's Up", "John", "Good Evening"], "Smith"]
```

Using this array structure in python, how do I create all possible sentences? i.e. Hey What's Up Smith/Hey John Smith/Hey Good Evening Smith. I've been trying to figure it out but my brain's too fried right now to think of the proper recursion/technique. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay. But I just want the ones that follow the pattern. I can be give more specification if necessary, but it should be pretty straightforward what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2):

It requires normalizing your input list a bit, so that it is a list of lists, rather than a list of (strings and lists).  Then it's easy, using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> w = [["Hey"], ["What's Up", "John", "Good Evening"], ["Smith"]]

>>> list(itertools.product(*w))
[('Hey', "What's Up", 'Smith'),
 ('Hey', 'John', 'Smith'),
 ('Hey', 'Good Evening', 'Smith')]

>>> map(' '.join, list(itertools.product(*w)))
["Hey What's Up Smith", 'Hey John Smith', 'Hey Good Evening Smith']
```